# How can I remove this DIV from this JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove from this code only the part that renders the `<div class="post-summary-text">` on this page https://andre.mototaxi.club/

I have some knowledge of JavaScript, but this code is too implicit for me.

```
//<![CDATA[
function removeHtmlTag(a, b) {
    if (a.indexOf("<") != -1) {
        for (var c = a.split("<"), d = 0; d < c.length; d++) c[d].indexOf(">") != -1 && (c[d] = c[d].substring(c[d].indexOf(">") + 1, c[d].length));
        a = c.join("")
    }
    for (b = b < a.length - 1 ? b : a.length - 2;
        " " != a.charAt(b - 1) && a.indexOf(" ", b) != -1;) b++;
    return a = a.substring(0, b - 1), a + "..."
}

function createSummaryAndThumb(a, b, c) {
    var d = document.getElementById(a),
        e = "",
        f = d.getElementsByTagName("img"),
        g = posts_no_thumb_sum;
    f.length >= 1 ? (e = '<div class="posts-thumb"><a href="' + b + '"><img src="' + f[0].src + '"/></a></div>', g = posts_thumb_sum) : (e = '<div class="posts-thumb" style="float:left;"><a href="' + b + '" title="' + c + '"><img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Gbn3dT1R9Yo/VPXSJ8lih_I/AAAAAAAALDQ/24wFWdfFvu4/s1600/sorry-image-not-available.png"/></a></div>', g = posts_thumb_sum);
    var h = e + '<div class="post-summary-text">' + removeHtmlTag(d.innerHTML, g) + "</div>";
    d.innerHTML = h
}
//]]>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this two lines as follows:

ORIGINAL

```
var h = e + '<div class="post-summary-text">' + removeHtmlTag(d.innerHTML, g) + "</div>";
d.innerHTML = h
```

SOLUTION

```
//remove this line
var h = e + '<div class="post-summary-text">' + removeHtmlTag(d.innerHTML, g) + "</div>";

//change this to be equal to e instead of h
d.innerHTML = e
```